# Angular hover in + key press events

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm pasting this sample code, which listens for `mouseenter` event and on `mouseenter` checks if `Ctrl` key is pressed. If yes, it applies some classes to the current target, which works fine, BUT only if the `Ctrl` key is pressed prior to the `mouseenter` event. What do I have to change for the same thing to happen also in the case where the `mouseenter` is first and then the `Ctrl` key is pressed?

html:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($event)"> Some content </div>
```

controller.js:

```
function hoverIn(event){
    if((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)){
        angular.element(event.currentTarget).addClass('current-element');
    }
}
```

Comment: your requirement is bit confusing , you want to apply class on all those element on which there was mouse click and after that user press CTRL?

Comment: You could add a listener for `keypress` and `keydown` events. Set and unset a flag in these listeners respectively if the key in question is `ctrl`. Now in your mouse event listeners you could check this flag to know whether `ctrl`` key is pressed or not.

Comment: I want to apply a class to the current element which I have hovered on and pressed ctrl key. And if I have already hovered on the element and then press ctrl key - I want the class to be applied also

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but I wanted to resolve it in case someone else came by it.

Changing your code to use ng-mousemove will get you what you want. Then in code handle both the true and false possibilities.

HTML:

```
<div ng-mousemove="mouseHover($event)"> Some content </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
scope.mouseHover = function ($event) {
    if ($event && $event.ctrlKey) {
        angular.element($event.currentTarget).addClass('actionCursor');
    }
    else {
        angular.element($event.currentTarget).removeClass('actionCursor');
    }
}
```